# Rounding to nearest fraction (half, quarter, etc.)

Tags: php, rounding, printf, floor, ceil

So, I need to create the following functions but my head can't think of any possibility in PHP without complicated math.

- Round **always** up to the nearest decimal (1.81 = 1.90, 1.89 = 1.90, 1.85 = 1.90)
- Round **always** down to the nearest decimal (1.81 = 1.80, 1.89 = 1.80, 1.85 = 1.80)
- Round **always** up to the nearest x.25 / x.50 / x.75 / x.00 (1.81 = 2, 1.32 = 1.50)
- Round **always** down to the nearest x.25 / x.50 / x.75 / x.00 (1.81 = 1.75, 1.32 = 1.25)
- Round **always** up to the nearest x.50 / 1 (1.23 = 1.50, 1.83 = 2)
- Round **always** down to the nearest x.50 / 1 (1.23 = 1, 1.83 = 1.50)

I have searched on Google for 2 hours now and the only things that came up were Excel forums. Is it possible with some simple lines of PHP?

Comment: Look for `round`, `ceil`... in PHP.net

Comment: I know that it's possible with    round and    ceil but I can't create the functions somehow.

Comment: 2 hours of googling could have written some possibly complicated, but working algorithms

Comment: This smells like homework..

Comment: @Wiseguy you're right.

Comment: @Catfish I need this actually for a webshop to round the prices of the products.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Since you're looking for *fourths* (`.00`, `.25`, `.50`, `.75`), multiply your number by 4, round to nearest whole number as desired (`floor` if down, `ceil` if up), then divide by 4.

*1.32, down to nearest fourth*:

> 1.32 * 4 = 5.28
>   floor(5.28) = 5.00
>   5.00 / 4 = **1.25**

Same principle applies for any other fractions, such as *thirds* or *eighths* (`.0`, `.125`, `.25`, `.375`, `.5`, `.625`, `.75`, `.875`). For example:

*1.77, up to nearest eighth*:

> 1.77 * 8 = 14.16
>   ceil(14.16) = 15.00
>   15.00 / 8 = **1.875**

---

Just for fun, you could write a function like this:

```
function floorToFraction($number, $denominator = 1)
{
    $x = $number * $denominator;
    $x = floor($x);
    $x = $x / $denominator;
    return $x;
}

echo floorToFraction(1.82);      // 1
echo floorToFraction(1.82, 2);   // 1.5
echo floorToFraction(1.82, 3);   // 1.6666666666667
echo floorToFraction(1.82, 4);   // 1.75
echo floorToFraction(1.82, 9);   // 1.7777777777778
echo floorToFraction(1.82, 25);  // 1.8
```

Comment: You guys are my heroes. Thanks. (And I don't know which one I have to except now as the answer).

Comment: I'd go with the answer that actually contains the solution code, rather than just a link elsewhere. Or you could accept the one that was posted first.

Comment: I wish i could give you hundreds of upvotes for this!

Comment: For anybody looking into this now: just use PHP's [round function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Comment: @James using `round()` alone does not provide the solution to the OPs question

Answer (score 5):

Please note that the answer isn't really water tight. Since we're dealing with floats here it's not guaranteed that when you divide the rounded number by the denominator it returns a neatly round number. It may return 1.499999999999 instead of 1.5. It's the nature of floating point numbers.

Another round is needed before returning the number from the function.

Just in case someone lands here from google like I did :)

Comment: Mind adding an example?

Comment: @Simon `round(round(2.24 * 4) / 4, 2)`: The inner round function makes it snap to the closest integer. The division can lead to strange floats, so the outer round function rounds it to 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Fx32 your little snippet works great -- maybe you should mention to change the places as needed (for example: `round(round(2.24 * 8) / 8, 3)` to get proper results such as .125, .875 to convert to nearest 1/8 fractional inches.

Answer (score 4):

According to the `mround()` function in Excel:

```
function MRound($num,$parts) {
    $res = $num * $parts;
    $res = round($res);
    return $res /$parts;
}
echo MRound(-1.38,4);//gives -1.5
echo MRound(-1.37,4);//gives -1.25
echo MRound(1.38,4);//gives 1.5
echo MRound(1.37,4);//gives 1.25
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at example #3 on here and it is half of your solution - http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: You guys are my heroes. Thanks. (And I don't know which one I have to except now as the answer).