# Round up decimal number according to fraction in PHP

Tags: php, rounding

I am working to convert an excel formula to php function. Now I am facing a problem that is round up as the fraction. Please let me explain it:

> - (2 * 18)/2.98 = 12.08 but according to my requirement it should be 12.25
>
>   - (2 * 18.5)/2.98 = 12.416 but according to my requirement it should be 12.50
>   - (2 * 18.8)/2.98 = 12.617 but according to my requirement it should be 12.75

In excel, it is done like :

> - ceiling(( 2 * 18 )/2.98,  0.25) = 12.25
>
>   - ceiling(( 2 * 18.5 )/2.98,  0.25) = 12.50
>   - ceiling(( 2 * 18.8 )/2.98,  0.25) = 12.75

I tried in PHP. Ceil() and Floor() do not serve the purpose as these 2 shall give output 13 and 12 accordingly.

Another one round() uses these options `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN, or PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD` which does not serve the purpose.

Anyone there to help me?

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903379/rounding-to-nearest-fraction-half-quarter-etc

Comment: @andreas thanks for your information. It helps also.

Comment: @ketan what did you edit?

Comment: @ahossain I just format your question properly. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36324171/revisions

Comment: @ahossain is none of the answers correct? You should mark the correct answer as accepted and/or upvote.

Comment: @andreas , yes, none the answer seems right in 100%, all they are partially correct. rather your link has given me proper solution. I used ceil() in replace of floor() for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903379/rounding-to-nearest-fraction-half-quarter-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function:

```
function fractionRound($num,$frac) {
  return ceil($num/$frac)*$frac;
}
```

call it this way:

```
echo fractionRound(( 2 * 18 )/2.98, 0.25);
```

it will round to the nearest 0.25 it will return **12.25**

Answer (score 0):

PHP only provides facility to round to a precision, with the options that you found. However, you can do something similar to what you want with a little inventive mathematics and a userland function.

Try:

```
function roundTo($value, $roundTo = 1)
{
    $inverse = 1 / $roundTo;
    return round($value * $inverse) / $inverse;
}
```

See: https://ideone.com/fojMrS

Note that if you want the `ceil` or `floor` functionality you'll have to create versions of this function for `ceil` and `floor`, this is just for `round`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$YourNumber = 12.08;
$int = $YourNumber * 4;
$int = ceil($int);

echo $YourNumber ." was the start <br>";
echo $int / 4 ." is the answer";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function roundQuarters($input)
{
    $rm = $input % 0.25;
    return $rm == 0 ? $input : $input - $rm + 0.25;
}
```

This will round the decimal up to the nearest 0.25, if it's also a divisor of 0.25, it'll return the same. Simple.

And you can replace 0.25 to whatever decimal you want or even parameterize that.