# Use column of parent query in subquery of a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

With this query:

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    `type`,
    `subtype`,
    `title`,
    `shortdesc`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM `story_comments`
     WHERE `parent_id` = t1.`id`) as comments,
    (SELECT
        (ROUND( (
            SELECT (SUM(`rating` * `count`) / SUM(`count`) ) ) * 2) ) / 2 as result
            FROM
                    (SELECT rating, COUNT(*) as count
                     FROM `story_ratings` WHERE `parent_id` = t1.`id`
                     GROUP BY rating) as val) as rating,
    `calls`,
    `user`
FROM
    `storys` t1
WHERE
    `open` = 1 AND
    `modremove` = 0 AND
    `modblock` = ''
ORDER BY
    `opening`
DESC LIMIT 16;
```

I get this error: #1054 - Unknown column 't1.id' in 'where clause', which is caused by the subquery in the subquery (subquery after FROM).

But the `t1.id` in the first subquery is working fine. Why cant I use it in the FROM-subquery? I also tried variables, which also didnt work:

```
SELECT @i := `id` id, `type`, `subtype`, `title`, `shortdesc`, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `story_comments` WHERE `parent_id` = t1.`id`) as comments, 

(SELECT (ROUND( (SELECT (SUM(`rating` * `count`) / SUM(`count`) ) ) * 2) ) / 2 as result FROM (SELECT rating, COUNT(*) as count FROM `story_ratings` WHERE `parent_id` = @i GROUP BY rating) as val) as rating,

`calls`, `user` FROM `storys` t1 WHERE `open` = 1 AND `modremove` = 0 AND `modblock` = '' ORDER BY `opening` DESC LIMIT 16;
```

With the `@i` variable, result returned NULL on every row, what is wrong.

Comment: Maybe look into Common Table Expressions (CTE), it might help clean up your SQL.

Comment: Can you please replace every instance of ` to ' in your query so that it works?

Comment: @DavidSöderlund The backtick is a quoted identifier for MySQL. Those are supposed to be names, not strings and in MySQL it should work fine, even if it is ugly (IMO)

Comment: I see, I figured as much. Was confused because the question was also tagged as sql-server.

Comment: the backticks are working perfectly.

Comment: @Dan MySQL doesn't support CTEs :(

Comment: Does mySQL support window functions? This code could be made pretty by cross applying this as rating -> SELECT ROUND(SUM(sr.rating) over (partition by t1.id) / count(*) OVER (partition by t1.id) * 2) / 2 AS totalRating FROM story_ratings as sr WHERE sr.[parent_id] = t1.[id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. So many nested subqueries. Instead of nesting queries to the ends of the earth, use `JOIN`s and aggregate your data to calculate what you need. I had to make some guesses about your table structures because you didn't supply them (something that you should always do when posting a database question).

```
SELECT
    S.id,
    S.type,
    S.subtype,
    S.title,
    S.shortdesc,
    COUNT(DISTINCT SC.id) AS comments,
    AVG(SR.rating) AS rating,
    calls,
    user
FROM
    Storys S  -- Storys isn't the plural of Story, BTW
LEFT OUTER JOIN Story_Comments SC ON SC.parent_id = S.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Story_Ratings SR ON SR.parent_id = S.id
WHERE
    S.open = 1 AND
    S.modremove = 0 AND
    S.modblock = ''
GROUP BY
    S.id,
    S.type,
    S.subtype,
    S.title,
    S.shortdesc,
    S.calls,
    S.user
ORDER BY
    opening
DESC LIMIT 16;
```

I don't think that the "* 2 ... / 2" does what you think it does, based on the various parentheses and the rounding might not be right here depending on the data type of your `rating` column (again, no table structures, so I'm stuck guessing).

I don't have a MySQL server handy, but testing this code on SQL Server (adjusting for difference in the `ROUND` function) gave the same results as your first query.

Comment: Thank you very much! With some changes, it worked. I really have to learn JOINs... In German, we also say "Storys" as the plural of "Story". The thing with *2 and /2 achieves something like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903379/rounding-to-nearest-fraction-half-quarter-etc). My next questions will have the structure included :)

Comment: Ahh. With all of the other column names and tables being in English I didn't suspect another language.