# PHP - Rounding of numbers to nearest multiple of 0.5

Tags: php

Just had a really simple question.

I'm making a review system and I want the scores to be rounded off to the nearest multiple of 0.5

So what I mean is:

> **0 / 0.5 / 1 / 1.5 / 2 / 2.5 /....**

What's the best way of doing this?

I currently have this code but this isn't working

```
$score = ($food + $staff + $value + $atmosphere) / 4;
$score = ceil($score * 2) / 2;
```

Comment: Similar question asked but with more options for rounding, take a read @
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903379/rounding-to-nearest-fraction-half-quarter-etc

Answer (score 6):

Use `round()` function:

```
$x = round($x * 2) / 2;
```

Comment: Multiplications are easier on the CPU than divisions, so this would be better: `$x = 0.5 * round($x * 2);`. Would the PHP parser be clever enough to do this conversion?

Comment: He still rounds off 2.5 to 3 for some reason?