# Round decimal number to .5 when decimal is below .5 - PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to round up decimal number to .5 if the decimal value is below or equal to .5 instead of rounding up to whole number?

Ex:

```
0.12  => 0.5
0.23  => 0.5
12.39 => 12.5...
```

but when the decimal value is greater than .5 round the number up

```
0.51   => 1.0
0.60   => 1.0
12.80  => 13.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Rounding of numbers to nearest multiple of 0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859270/php-rounding-of-numbers-to-nearest-multiple-of-0-5)

Comment: @GilesCorreiaMorton no it doesn't , I tried 0.14 the result is 0.0

Comment: Maybe You only need `ceil($x * 2) / 2`.

Comment: @RomanHocke yes, ceil() does the job. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x` is your variable do `Ceil($x * 2) / 2`
Which will round your number to the nearest whole number or 0.5

Comment: Did you mean to use `ceil()`?

Comment: 0.12 * 2 -> 0.24 - you floor that you get 0 and not 0.5. I think your solution would work with `ceil()`