# Round second digit after decimal to produce nice number

Tags: php, rounding

Need to round `30.61` to `30.60`, Any built-in function for PHP to do this ?

Comment: So you want to round `30.69` to `30.70`? There's no built in function that I'm aware of, but should be quite simple.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903379/rounding-to-nearest-fraction-half-quarter-etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding to nearest fraction (half, quarter, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903379/rounding-to-nearest-fraction-half-quarter-etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your desired output correctly, that you only want to round the second decimal point, you can round with 1 decimal presicion, then use `numer_format()` to ensure you get the correct number of decimals.

```
$num = 30.61;
echo number_format(round($num, 1), 2);
```

- [`round()` documentation](https://php.net/round)
- [`number_format()` documentation](https://php.net/number-format)
- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/i2YV5)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
 $num = 3.61;
 /*round to nearest decimal place*/
 $test_number = round($num,1);
 /* ans :3.6
 format to 2 decimal place*/
 $test_number = sprintf ("%.2f", $test_number);
 /* ans : 3.60 */
```